# How can I enable right-ctrl usage in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, ctrl

I would like to be able to use <kbd>right</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd> inside the VM.

I have the Guest Additions software installed, so I no longer need the <kbd>right</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd> feature to escape from the VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to preferences and in Input change the binding from <kbd>Right</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd> to something else.